# How to convert a concatenated image to the its original one, Python

Tags: python, image, merge, concatenation

Suppose `im` is an image with the size of *100*100*3*. The following code gives the corresponding concatenated image:

```
im = np.concatenate((
        im[:,:,0].reshape((100*100,)),
        im[:,:,1].resh‌​ape((100*100,)),
        im[:‌​,:,2].reshape((100*1‌​00,))
    ),
    axis=0
)
```

Now we have a row array with a size of *1*30000*.

The question is that how we can get back from the concatenated image to the original one?

Comment: how did you get this result. can you print the shape of im

Comment: Stackflow does not allowed me to upload. The picture looks like a nine-small original figure, _(3*3)_. Each row is in the different channel.

Comment: print (im.shape) ?

Comment: the shape is: _(30000,)_

Comment: I can't figure it out. it should have a dimension of 2.

Comment: ` im = np.concatenate((im[:,:,0].reshape((100*100,)),im[:,:,1].reshape((100*100,)),im[:,:,2].reshape((100*100,))),axis=0)` gives me _(30000,)

Comment: the two functions you said right now are different. So are you using the first one or the second. if the second you should have two dimension and I have the answer to.

Comment: The second one is correct, however it gives me a row array. I will edit the function now. Because each `.reshape((100*100,)` is a row, and concatenated of the three raw is still a row.

Comment: do reshape to each row first into (100,100) and then apply what I wrote down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
im = im.reshape(300,100)
s = np.zeros((100,100,3))
s[:,:,0] = im[:100,:]
s[:,:,1] = im[100:200,:]
s[:,:,2] = im[200:,:]
```

Comment: try again by adding the first line

Comment: First is that the number _100_ in the last line should be 200. Second, why the colour has been changed? the images are the same but the colour is different

Comment: TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data

Comment: The original format is unit8, but I think the converted one, `s` has another format. How to figure out this? if they have the same format, I think it works.

Comment: I deleted the code I wrote it was a mistake. the error might be cause BGR or RGB try to convert them using some library. the array now constructed into it is origin you just need to convert color. if I answered your question plz mark it an answer.